# MySQL/Apache: Replace spaces with underscores only in certain URLs

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, wordpress, replace

I'm having a problem with some images I'm using on my WordPress blog. After a migration I renamed every image replacing spaces with underscores, so

HIDDEN_264_4062_FOTO_IDF los MID.jpg

was renamed to

HIDDEN_264_4062_FOTO_IDF_los_MID.jpg

But althought the trick was necessary and worked for most of the posts, some of them try to find the old image, with spaces:

This is not found

http://www.example.com/files/HIDDEN_264_4062_FOTO_IDF%20los%20MID.jpg

and this should be the right URL

http://www.example.com/files/HIDDEN_264_4062_FOTO_IDF_los_MID.jpg

Careful, though, 'cause the "%20" is only shown on the browser: the text on the database shows spaces, not "%20".

I'd like to know if maybe I could make a SQL query in my WordPress MySQL database that replaces spaces in .jpg files with underscores. The path of the images is always the same, so the rule should transform this:

/files/HIDDEN_264_4062_FOTO_IDF los MID.jpg

/files/HIDDEN_264_4062_FOTO_IDF_los_MID.jpg

the "/files/HIDDEN_264_" part is always the same, but the rest varies. Is some way to perform this? Maybe a rewrite rule on Apache (our current webserver)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mysql `replace` function like:

```
mysql> UPDATE your_table SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, ' ', '_') WHERE your_field like '/files/HIDDEN_264_%';
```

This will replace all spaces with underscores in the file name saved in the field `your_field`.

In order to replace the spaces in part of your string, you can use `substring` function:

```
mysql> UPDATE your_table SET your_field = concat(REPLACE(substring(your_field from 1 for 30), ' ', '_'), substring(your_field from 31) WHERE your_field like '/files/HIDDEN_264_%';
```

The above example, replaces the spaces only in the first 30 characters in `your_field`. You can customise it according to the type of data you have. If you can not determine the right length (30 in this example), you can use `locate` function to search for specific pattern (delimiter).

I can not tell you more as I don't know the format of your data.

Comment: I'm affraid that's not entirely working. I've tried that and what I think it does is to replace EVERY SPACE on the post_content field, and I only want to replace the spaces on that images' links. In fact, there was a % missing at the beginning of the final "like" statement. What I've tried is this:

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, ' ', '_') WHERE post_content like '%/files/HIDDEN_264_%';

But again, it's not entirely right :( Is there someway to restrict the replacement to the links?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It will replace every space in your field. I don't know that it does contain other data in addition to the file name.

Comment: Yep, that's one of the main difficulties, I guess. The links I have to replace are just part of the articles (the HTML content of each article is in the wp_post table, in the post_content field), but I only need to replace the space on that links. Can it be done?

Comment: Khaled, thank you so much for taking the time to try to solve this. I don't think the substring function could be the answer. 

Don't know if you know wordpress, but what i'm trying to do is, in every post, if there is a link with an image and its filename has a space, replace that with an underscore. So I'm not able to know where exactly is the link, and in fact, the same post (wp_posts->post-content) is an HTML text that can contain more than one image that has spaces, and all of them should be replaced with "_". 

What I need is to replace only the links, that follow that pattern HIDDEN...

Answer (score 0):

even if into the database the URL uses spaces when wordpress sends it
to the browser will do URL encoding so it will convert spaces with their entity %20
you can try the SQL query above, but do a backup before 
    mysqldump --all-databases > my-back.sql

Comment: Thanks for the comment silviud, I was going to do so anyway, but it's always great to remind someone these safe measures in case something goes wrong...